# Align <li> horizontally across width of page

Tags: html, css, alignment, scale

I'm learning HTML/CSS, and I started to recreate the Apple website. This is what I've got so far.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHfYP.jpg

I've gotten to the four promos at the bottom of the page, and I don't know how to make these properly. On the real site, if you zoom out you can see that the promo images are actually wider but when zoomed in they are cropped and aligned properly. How would one recreate this?

Here are the four promo images I got from the resources:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPneZ.jpg

I looked at the source code and found that it is created with li elements, so I went ahead and created one.

Here's my code

HTML:

```
<body>

    <div class="nav" align="center">
        <a href="http://www.apple.com/"><img src="http://goo.gl/VfB5zk"></a>
        <a href="http://www.apple.com/mac/"><img src="http://goo.gl/iwWkpP"></a>
        <a href="http://www.apple.com/iphone/"><img src="http://goo.gl/vgZM2X"></a>
        <a href="http://www.apple.com/watch/"><img src="http://goo.gl/uPwhwi"></a>
        <a href="http://www.apple.com/ipad/"><img src="http://goo.gl/Tjs3Ux"></a>
        <a href="http://www.apple.com/ipod/"><img src="http://goo.gl/i4EE4Y"></a>
        <a href="http://www.apple.com/itunes/"><img src="http://goo.gl/l19lzX"></a>
        <a href="http://www.apple.com/support/"><img src="http://goo.gl/P1Lsht"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron" align="center">
        <h1>Start something new.</h1>
        <p>When you start with amazing products, you can create amazing things.</p>
        <br>
        <a href="http://www.apple.com/start-something-new/">View the gallery</a>
        <br>
        <img src="Images/Jumbotron Banner.png">
    </div>

    <div class="promos">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.apple.com/ipad-air-2/change/"><img src="Images/iPad.jpg"></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url("Fonts/Myriad_Set_Ultra_Light/stylesheet.css");
@import url("Fonts/Myriad_Set_Light/stylesheet.css");

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: "Myriad Set Ultra Light";
}

.nav {
    background-color: #646464;
}

.nav img {
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
}

.jumbotron {
    font-family: "Myriad Set Ultra Light";
}

.jumbotron h1 {
    font-size: 64px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.jumbotron p {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: "Myriad Set Light";
}

.jumbotron a {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: "Myriad Set Light";
    color: #3ba3d7;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.jumbotron img {
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    right: -9999px;
    margin: auto;
}

.promos {
    margin-top: 450px;
}

.promos li {
    list-style: none;
}

.promos img {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use inline-block display or float left,

e.g.

```
.promos li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

or

```
.promos li {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: That partly works, but I need the images to grow/shrink to fit on one line. Right now they are too wide so they move down. 

http://i.imgur.com/relUWde.jpg

Comment: just set the same % width on your li, like if you have 4 list item, you can add, `width: 24.87777%` to the previous CSS

Comment: It's starting to work, but they overlap, and for some reason one of them doesn't want to move up there. I'm going to just Photoshop them to make them less wide.  http://i.imgur.com/wQgDGwX.jpg